# scipy curve_fit returning lower bound value

Tags: python, parameters, scipy, data-fitting

I have a function that I want to fit to the data, and I have a guess of what the parameters must be, but when I fit the function with the initial guests and bounds the fit return only the lower boundary for one of the parameters. Even if I change the boundaries, the alpha_ parameters is always the lower boundary. Here is the code:

```
def correction_function(z, A, z_c, alpha_):
    return (A * np.power(z, 2) * np.exp(-np.power((z/z_c), alpha_)))

x_data = [0.0025000000000000001, 0.0074999999999999997, 0.012500000000000001, 0.017499999999999998, 0.022499999999999999, 0.0275, 0.032500000000000001, 0.037500000000000006, 0.042500000000000003, 0.047500000000000001, 0.052500000000000005, 0.057500000000000002, 0.0625, 0.067500000000000004, 0.072500000000000009, 0.077499999999999999, 0.082500000000000004, 0.087500000000000008, 0.092499999999999999, 0.097500000000000003, 0.10250000000000001, 0.1075, 0.1125, 0.11750000000000001, 0.1225, 0.1275, 0.13250000000000001, 0.13750000000000001, 0.14250000000000002, 0.14749999999999999, 0.1525, 0.1575, 0.16250000000000001, 0.16750000000000001, 0.17250000000000001, 0.17750000000000002, 0.1825, 0.1875, 0.1925, 0.19750000000000001, 0.20250000000000001, 0.20750000000000002, 0.21249999999999999, 0.2175, 0.2225, 0.22750000000000001, 0.23250000000000001, 0.23750000000000002, 0.24249999999999999, 0.2475, 0.2525, 0.25750000000000001, 0.26250000000000001, 0.26750000000000002, 0.27250000000000002, 0.27750000000000002, 0.28250000000000003, 0.28750000000000003, 0.29249999999999998, 0.29749999999999999, 0.30249999999999999, 0.3075, 0.3125, 0.3175, 0.32250000000000001, 0.32750000000000001, 0.33250000000000002, 0.33750000000000002, 0.34250000000000003, 0.34750000000000003, 0.35250000000000004, 0.35749999999999998, 0.36249999999999999, 0.36749999999999999, 0.3725, 0.3775, 0.38250000000000001, 0.38750000000000001, 0.39250000000000002, 0.39750000000000002]

y_data = [0.0, 2714.0, 6116.0, 7371.0, 9134.0, 9134.0, 8445.0, 8257.0, 8446.0, 9257.0, 11076.0, 12533.0, 12761.0, 11939.0, 12002.0, 12343.0, 13220.0, 14164.0, 14584.0, 15273.0, 15179.0, 14264.0, 14603.0, 15420.0, 15361.0, 15480.0, 16446.0, 17508.0, 19001.0, 19043.0, 18968.0, 18596.0, 18686.0, 18480.0, 19462.0, 19672.0, 20841.0, 22097.0, 23246.0, 24085.0, 24126.0, 23526.0, 22624.0, 22491.0, 21883.0, 21290.0, 21063.0, 19879.0, 18824.0, 17181.0, 15809.0, 15745.0, 17262.0, 19663.0, 22068.0, 22657.0, 22121.0, 20647.0, 20100.0, 19418.0, 19477.0, 19453.0, 20282.0, 20706.0, 21027.0, 20365.0, 19868.0, 18350.0, 17041.0, 15142.0, 13702.0, 12106.0, 10833.0, 10004.0, 9283.0, 8700.0, 8607.0, 8500.0, 8861.0, 9132.0]

params, params_covariance = optimize.curve_fit(correction_function, xdata, ydata, p0 = [2.0e6, 0.2, 1.5], bounds=((0.1e6, 0.15, 1.4), (10.0e6, 0.25, 1.6)))
```

How do I fix this so that all the parameters are fitted?

I tried changing the boundaries, changing the method, max_nfev, and other inputs of the function, but the fit still returns the same lower boundary for alpha_.

Answer (score 2):

This is a complete guess, but it looks as if your bounds are arbitrarily attempting to restrict the solution to a preconceived set of parameters. Those can be made much more broad and the guess made more generic, and the fit is still fine (or at least looks like it). The data are extremely noisy, so identifying a good fit is difficult.

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy import optimize


def correction_function(z: np.ndarray, A: float, z_c: float, alpha: float) -> np.ndarray:
    return (
        A
        * z**2
        * np.exp(
            -(z / z_c)**alpha
        )
    )


x_data = np.array((
    0.0025, 0.0075, 0.0125, 0.0175, 0.0225, 0.0275, 0.0325, 0.0375,
    0.0425, 0.0475, 0.0525, 0.0575, 0.0625, 0.0675, 0.0725, 0.0775,
    0.0825, 0.0875, 0.0925, 0.0975, 0.1025, 0.1075, 0.1125, 0.1175,
    0.1225, 0.1275, 0.1325, 0.1375, 0.1425, 0.1475, 0.1525, 0.1575,
    0.1625, 0.1675, 0.1725, 0.1775, 0.1825, 0.1875, 0.1925, 0.1975,
    0.2025, 0.2075, 0.2125, 0.2175, 0.2225, 0.2275, 0.2325, 0.2375,
    0.2425, 0.2475, 0.2525, 0.2575, 0.2625, 0.2675, 0.2725, 0.2775,
    0.2825, 0.2875, 0.2925, 0.2975, 0.3025, 0.3075, 0.3125, 0.3175,
    0.3225, 0.3275, 0.3325, 0.3375, 0.3425, 0.3475, 0.3525, 0.3575,
    0.3625, 0.3675, 0.3725, 0.3775, 0.3825, 0.3875, 0.3925, 0.3975,
))

y_data = np.array((
        0,  2714,  6116,  7371,  9134,  9134,  8445,  8257,  8446,
     9257, 11076, 12533, 12761, 11939, 12002, 12343, 13220, 14164,
    14584, 15273, 15179, 14264, 14603, 15420, 15361, 15480, 16446,
    17508, 19001, 19043, 18968, 18596, 18686, 18480, 19462, 19672,
    20841, 22097, 23246, 24085, 24126, 23526, 22624, 22491, 21883,
    21290, 21063, 19879, 18824, 17181, 15809, 15745, 17262, 19663,
    22068, 22657, 22121, 20647, 20100, 19418, 19477, 19453, 20282,
    20706, 21027, 20365, 19868, 18350, 17041, 15142, 13702, 12106,
    10833, 10004,  9283,  8700,  8607,  8500,  8861,  9132,
))

p0 = 5e6, 0.1, 1

params, _ = optimize.curve_fit(
    f=correction_function, xdata=x_data, ydata=y_data, p0=p0,
    bounds=(
        (     0,      0,      0),
        (np.inf, np.inf, np.inf),
    ),
)
print(params)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax: plt.Axes
ax.plot(x_data, y_data, label='experiment')
ax.plot(x_data, correction_function(x_data, *p0), label='guess')
ax.plot(x_data, correction_function(x_data, *params), label='fit')
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

```
[9.79571861e+06 4.40508921e-02 7.12502293e-01]
```

[image: fit plots]

A better fit will require a better model and/or less noisy data and/or much more data. For example, change your exponents in the model and the fit improves greatly:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy import optimize


def correction_function(z: np.ndarray, A: float, alpha: float, beta: float, z_c: float) -> np.ndarray:
    return (
        A
        * z**alpha
        * np.exp(
            -(z / z_c)**beta
        )
    )


x_data = np.array((
    0.0025, 0.0075, 0.0125, 0.0175, 0.0225, 0.0275, 0.0325, 0.0375,
    0.0425, 0.0475, 0.0525, 0.0575, 0.0625, 0.0675, 0.0725, 0.0775,
    0.0825, 0.0875, 0.0925, 0.0975, 0.1025, 0.1075, 0.1125, 0.1175,
    0.1225, 0.1275, 0.1325, 0.1375, 0.1425, 0.1475, 0.1525, 0.1575,
    0.1625, 0.1675, 0.1725, 0.1775, 0.1825, 0.1875, 0.1925, 0.1975,
    0.2025, 0.2075, 0.2125, 0.2175, 0.2225, 0.2275, 0.2325, 0.2375,
    0.2425, 0.2475, 0.2525, 0.2575, 0.2625, 0.2675, 0.2725, 0.2775,
    0.2825, 0.2875, 0.2925, 0.2975, 0.3025, 0.3075, 0.3125, 0.3175,
    0.3225, 0.3275, 0.3325, 0.3375, 0.3425, 0.3475, 0.3525, 0.3575,
    0.3625, 0.3675, 0.3725, 0.3775, 0.3825, 0.3875, 0.3925, 0.3975,
))

y_data = np.array((
        0,  2714,  6116,  7371,  9134,  9134,  8445,  8257,  8446,
     9257, 11076, 12533, 12761, 11939, 12002, 12343, 13220, 14164,
    14584, 15273, 15179, 14264, 14603, 15420, 15361, 15480, 16446,
    17508, 19001, 19043, 18968, 18596, 18686, 18480, 19462, 19672,
    20841, 22097, 23246, 24085, 24126, 23526, 22624, 22491, 21883,
    21290, 21063, 19879, 18824, 17181, 15809, 15745, 17262, 19663,
    22068, 22657, 22121, 20647, 20100, 19418, 19477, 19453, 20282,
    20706, 21027, 20365, 19868, 18350, 17041, 15142, 13702, 12106,
    10833, 10004,  9283,  8700,  8607,  8500,  8861,  9132,
))

p0 = 5e4, 0.5, 10, 0.5

params, _ = optimize.curve_fit(
    f=correction_function, xdata=x_data, ydata=y_data, p0=p0,
    bounds=(
        (     0,      0,      0,      0),
        (np.inf, np.inf, np.inf, np.inf),
    ),
)
print(params)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax: plt.Axes
ax.plot(x_data, y_data, label='experiment')
ax.plot(x_data, correction_function(x_data, *p0), label='guess')
ax.plot(x_data, correction_function(x_data, *params), label='fit')
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

```
[4.59122971e+04 4.88407210e-01 6.20758888e+00 3.76755600e-01]
```

[image: second fit]

Answer (score 1):

The usual methods of non-linear regression involve iterative calculus starting from "guessed" values of the parameters.

To avoid initial guess one can use a non conventional method which isn't iterative. The application of this method is shown below in the case of the function that you consider.

Note that in the available doccument (copy below) the symbols are different from the symbols in the OP's question. One have to take care to avoid confusion. An attempt to clarify the relationship was made.

[image]

The result is :

[image]

Details of the numerical calculus :

[image]

NOTE :

The method of fitting without initial guess is in fact a linear regression but wrt an integral equation instead of wrt the equation to be fitted. The integral equation must be linear and have the equation to be fitted as a solution. In the present case the integral equation is :

[image]

Once an approximate value of p is found it is easy to compute the other parameters thanks to a simple linear regression.

As a consequence the criteria of fitting isn't exactly classical such as LMSE, LMSRE, LMSAE or etc. If such classical criteria of fitting is strictly required one have to come back to classical method of nonlinear regression with initial guesses. The above values found for the parameters can be very good initial values to start the iterative process.

More information about the general principle of this method : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales

IN ADDITION :

Comparison to the above results (method without guess) to the non-linear regression (Iterative method with initial guesses, criteria LMSE ). :

[image]

There is a slight difference between the fitted curves especially where the scatter is the more large.